# Disabled text color for buttons not properly working in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I am working on a new .NET Maui App and I have defined a button Style that looks like this:

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GreenButtonBrush"
                         EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#64ca64"
                      Offset="0.0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#359b35"
                      Offset="1.0" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Color x:Key="Local100">#ffff00</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Local500">#ff0000</Color>

    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="GreenButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Key=GreenButtonBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Key=Local100}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Fill" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Key=Local500}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The green gradient background looks good and the default text color (yellow for testing purposes) is also used. When I change the text color for the disabled state in XAML while the App is running, it is properly applied.

However, if I save my changes and restart the App, the text color for the disabled state is black.

Does anyone have an idea why my disabled button text color is not properly working? I know that I am in the `IsEnabled = false` state, because if I change the button's state, the color gets properly updated to the yellow color.

I am testing my work on Android 10, 11, and 13 devices.

**Update 03/12/2024**

I tried to combine the control with all styles into one element. Unfortunately, I have the same behavior.

```
<Button Grid.Column="2"
        Background="{StaticResource Key=GreenButtonBrush}"
        BindingContext="{Binding Path=StartOverButton}"
        HeightRequest="40"
        CornerRadius="5"
        Text="{Binding Path=Caption}"
        TextColor="{StaticResource Key=Gray100}"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        TextTransform="Uppercase"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        Command="{Binding Path=ClickCommand}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a DataTrigger?   `<DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">`

Comment: DataTrigger has no "Property". If I use `<DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">`, I have the same behavior as described in my initial post.

Comment: Oh I am sorry i was not paying attention i guess, Can you tell me what .NET maui version are you on?

Comment: .net8.0, I target Android API Level 21 (5.0) as minimum, the NuGet packages for Microsoft.Maui.* are 8.0.7. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let's test something out if you don't mind what if you did this without using a style does that work?

Comment: I tested it and copied it into my original question, because the character limitations for comments here are too strict. Unfortunately, no difference. I set the disabled color to red to make that I would notice a difference. Nothing is red.

Comment: Ok then try this, instead of using a Binding in your IsEnabled property in your button force it to false, I have a feeling your binding might be broken because I just tried it and it works fine

Comment: I am using a view model for all my buttons that contains a property for the button's caption, click command, and the IsEnabled state. I do not see any binding exceptions in the output. If I edit the name in XAML to something wrong (like IsEnabled2), I see binding errors. And as I described initially, when I change the color in XAML at run-time, I see the correct colors. But I do not see them in normal use (constant color or static resource).

Comment: Can you create a sample where i can reproduce this, so i can check it

Comment: I found the solution, @FreakyAli. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem and I wanted to share it in case someone runs into the same problem. Shoutout to **FreakyAli** for supporting my bug search!

I created the project for the new App in Visual Studio 2022 and it created a file Styles.xaml that contains a range of different default styles.

The default style for buttons (listed below) contains setters for disabled buttons that override the text color with theme colors. These colors win over my color definitions although I am explicitly referencing my custom button style. Since I have custom styles for all my buttons in my App, I removed the default style from Styles.xaml and now all my buttons look and work as expected.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource PrimaryDarkText}}" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource PrimaryDark}}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="14,10"/>
    <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="44"/>
    <Setter Property="MinimumWidthRequest" Value="44"/>
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Awesome, I thought you might have deleted all those default styles(Most people do). Lesson for me too here!!